# Sharing settings across unrelated SBT projects or in nested projects

Tags: sbt

A common way to share SBT settings is to have a multi-module build.

There are two use cases which I am not able to correctly handle:

1. Sharing SBT settings across unrelated projects (for example, library versions across different projects you don't want to keep under the same VCS tree)
2. Sharing SBT settings from root project to arbitrary nested modules. I have put some shared settings in `<root>/project/Build.scala` but when I try to import them in `<root>/subproject/build.sbt` they are not visible.

What's the proper way to handle these uses cases in SBT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to share settings between completely unrelated builds, then the best solution is to write an sbt plugin (this is very simple) that will be used used by your different projects. This is the solution used by sbt since it has been split into different modules ([see sbt-houserules](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-houserules)).

You'll find all you need in the [sbt documentation on how to write a plugin](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Plugins.html#Creating+an+auto+plugin).

Comment: If I understand it correctly I create a project for my plugin, I publish it in my local maven repo and I simply add a libraryDependency  on it?

Comment: Yes, but with `addSbtPlugin`, not `libraryDependency`

Comment: I make my question more general, do you know by chance how to answer the second question?